# Pinescript Longs only and Shorts only if condition is met

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am trying to add condition to my script that will only long if there was a Pi Cycle Bottom and short only if there was a Pi Cycle Top

both Pi Cycle top and bottom work - show on the chart

but I can not figure out how to make it work

I have added in front of script:

```
LongsOnly = false
ShortsOnly = false
```

and after Pi Cycle

```
PiCycleTop = ta.crossunder(ma_long, ma_short) ? src + src / 100 * 10 : na
plotshape(PiCycleTop, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.normal, text='Pi Cycle top', color=color.new(color.red, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.abovebar)
if PiCycleTop
    ShortsOnly = true

PiCycleBottom = ta.crossunder(ma_bottomshort, ma_bottomlong) ? src + src / 100 * 10 : na
plotshape(PiCycleBottom, style=shape.labeldown, size=size.normal, text='Pi Cycle Bottom', color=color.new(color.green, 0), textcolor=color.new(color.white, 0), location=location.belowbar)
if PiCycleBottom
    LongsOnly = true
```

...
to enter trades

```
if LongsOnly and  (condition sample)
    strategy.entry("buy", strategy.long, comment="Long", alert_message=OpenLong, alert_message=CloseShort)
if ShortsOnly and (condition sample)
    strategy.entry("sell", strategy.short, comment="Short", alert_message=OpenShort, alert_message=CloseLong)`
```

But it does not work, I tried different things but can not change LongsOnly and ShortsOnly to true

as above diffeernt if's to change LongsOnly and ShortsOnly to true